# Image upload and save in one php script

Tags: php, image, laravel-4

I want to upload a image from a remote server to my current server (server and backend migration) i am using laravel 4 and this is a 1 time use script so no need to worry about protecting it.

```
        if (strpos($check_image_arr['url'], '/product/'))
            {
        try
            {
                if (! file_exists ( "$destinationPath"))
                {
            mkdir("$destinationPath", 0777);
                }
            copy($check_image_arr['url'],$destinationPath."temp.jpg");
            echo "<img src=$destinationPath"."$filename >";

            $file          = file_get_contents($destinationPath);
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/img/product_images/'.'$check->id';
            $filename        = '$check->id'.".png";
            $uploadSuccess   = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
            die;


            }
        catch (Exception $e)
            {
            echo "$e";
            die;

            }
```

any suggestions will help thanks.

EDIT:: i found my solution

```
if (strpos($check_image_arr['url'], '/product/'))
    {

        if (! file_exists ( "$destinationPath"))
        {
    mkdir("$destinationPath", 0777);
        }
    copy($check_image_arr['url'],$destinationPath."temp.jpg");
    imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents(__DIR__."/img/product_images/"."$check->id"."/"."temp.jpg")),"temp.png");
    copy("temp.png",$destinationPath.$filename);
    }
```

Comment: Current output is "Call to a member function move() on a non-object"

Comment: Why not zip the folder and unzip at the destination since its a one time transfer?

Comment: trying to take advantage of the laravel any image input and defined image output

Comment: Don't see any advantage on that other than putting load on 2 servers, but good luck with that ;)

Comment: the issue it this is the back end to a app, they need PNG's to work with so i need to grab the url of current image location (got that from database as all image locations very) then i need to upload that image to a static location (see the copy functions above) that is fine then i need to grab that image and make it a PNG and name it the a incrementing number now thats where i am having a issue.

Comment: You said **migration**, if you're migrating the images are already on the proper format, so all you would have to do is move from one place to another. If that is the case the fastest and that would be less burden on to the 2 servers would be compressing the folder and decompressing at the destination moving only the compressed file alone. If at the end of that all you need to do is change the files to PNG that would still be easier as you would need to run a single command to convert all the files on a given folder from jpg to png.

Comment: Migration is correct, but the requirements are have changed from the first server to this server. The application has been rebuilt in a different way to reflect the upgrade in the back-end.